# Why was $1 \text{ OR } 1$ undefined in Boole's logic?

Tags: logic, math-history, boolean-algebra

I read that Boole's original OR function in which 1 or 1 was undefined then it has been modified so that while the formerly undefined case is now defined it is defined to 0(XOR) .
1- why Boole's original OR function in which 1 or 1 was undefined ?
2- why they redefine it ?

Comment: Please can you give a reference for the source that you have been reading (as it's wrong).

Comment: ones and zeros understanding boolean algebra
c.h 4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have read is misrepresenting Boole. See page 57 of Boole's [Investigation of the Laws of Thought](http://www.ccapitalia.net/descarga/docs/1847-boole-laws-of-thought.pdf). Boole used $x + y(1-x)\,$ for inclusive disjunction and $x(1-y) + y(1-x)\,$ for exclusive disjunction. So Boole's definitions give $1 \lor 1 = 1 + 1 \cdot (1 - 1) = 1\,$ and $1 \oplus 1 = 1\cdot 0 + 1\cdot 0 = 0\,$ just as we would expect today.